# File storage with SFTP connector and mounting capability on windows machine

Tags: azure, cloud, blob, infrastructure

My client will be sending files daily from an SFTP server. I need to persist those files in a storage solution in Azure and mount it to a windows machine because a thick client will use it.

SFTP is available in Azure Blob Storage in preview but is not mountable to a windows machine.

Azure Net App files are mountable on a windows machine but is not compatible with SFTP.

Is my question there an azure service that can meet those requirements?
My suggested solution is to store data received files via sftp in azure blob storage and then sync it with azure net app files that I will mount.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Files is the way to go, with the ability to mount them in Windows as Shared Drives via SMB (make sure your organisation does not block SMB protocol). Step-by-step is available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows

Few months ago, support to expose as SFTP was also announced for Azure Storage, which makes the perfect target as FTP share.

Alternatively, you could also opt to install Azure Storage Explorer free app and configure connections to your Azure storage. This works using old-plain HTTPS, hence able to access across firewalls, etc.